# jquery not working with laravel orchid button

Tags: laravel, orchid

```
 public function commandBar(): array
    {
        
         $buttons[] = Button::make('Preview')->id('ddd')
                   ->icon('check')
                   ->method('preview');
                   
        return $buttons;
    }
```

I m new in Laravel Orchid.I wanted to target the preview button by id and perform some javascript action.

Please let me know in which file should i write javascript?

Comment: You should post a bit more details about what you want to achieve, together with the actual JavaScript code. Maybe there's just a typo somewhere or some logical issue.

Answer (score 0):

The most common answer is in [Orchid documentation](https://orchid.software/en/docs/javascript/):

> Orchid’s seamless administrative panel experience is powered by Turbo.

```
document.addEventListener("turbo:load", () => {
    console.log('Page loaded');
})
```

Since all resources will be loaded on the first call, classic calls will not work. Make sure that your script not waiting for document load and so on.